# Exception Class Name: org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException

Tags: java, spring, gwt

I am getting the following exception when trying to call:

```
ManagementServiceV1X0 managementService = (ManagementServiceV1X0)factory.getPort(ManagementServiceV1X0.class, ManagementServiceV1.class);

Exception Class Name: org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException
Error Code: null - Screen Code: null - Description: ID - Teknical Error - Detail: org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'com.test.product.management.v1x0.ManagementServiceV1X0.endpoint' for locale 'en_US'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'com.test.product.management.v1x0.ManagementServiceV1X0.endpoint' for locale 'en_US'.
```

Looks like the message properties file is missing, or the key `com.test.product.management.v1x0.ManagementServiceV1X0.endpoint` is not defined in the message file.

Comment: I do not have written `IndexedProductManagementServiceV1X0`